# Google Translate api in my website

Tags: google-translate

Hi in the below code I am using in my website but it was displaying like this
http://rushdainfotech.in/contact.php
Can any one please help me

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google translate aspect seems to be working fine.  However, there is a global style that you have:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Simply comment out or move it to be class based the width: 100% and it should look fine.